# Archive or clone specific files/directories with git (specifically github)

Tags: git, curl, twitter-bootstrap, zip, github-api

I'm trying to make a customizer similar to the one used by Twitter for their Bootstrap framework (http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/customize.html). I have a github repo that I need to be able to specify certain files and directories to download as a zip.

I've looked into possible solutions, and have a few ideas on how I can accomplish this. But I'd like some feedback.

`git archive` will not work because the repo is on github and apparently they do not allow this. Also, I've not been able to find a way to specify files to include or exclude in the command itself.

My first thought was to create a script that clones the repo into a temporary directory and then delete the files I don't want in the zip (including git files). The problem with this is I'd always be downloading everything — even the stuff I don't want in the zip.

My other idea is to have a list of files to download and a script that loops through that list  to get the files from raw.github.com.

What is the best way to do this? Does anyone know how Twitter accomplishes this for Bootstrap?

EDIT: Just to be clear, I'm not trying to create my own custom builder for Bootstrap; I have my own, unrelated project on github.

Comment: So basically you are asking how to do download as less as possible, aren't you?

Comment: @the.malkolm Right, I only want to download what the person has specified that they want included in the zip.

Comment: No, you can't as git-archive is disabled at github you can't do something like this. You can download only a single branch, you can download only the last revision (w/o history) but there is no way to download a subtree only :(

Comment: The way Bootstrap does this is -- they have a server-side process (http://bootstrap.herokuapp.com/) to which they send a POST request with the list of features you selected, and this process then packages and serves the ZIP. Not sure how *exactly* they do it within the heroku app, but I imagine they just fetch the latest raw files from the list from GitHub, ZIP them up and send as the response. They might even cache the files locally and sync them with the GitHub repo after commits.

Comment: @IvanZuzak Thanks for the response, Ivan! This is exactly what they are doing. I posted an answer below with a link to the GitHub repo where they keep the code for bootstrap.herokuap.com

Comment: no problem, jason. + nice of the bootstrap team to open-source **everything** :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I contacted Jacob Thorton, one of the developers of Bootstrap, and he pointed me in the direction of the GitHub repo for their Heroku-hosted server-side process that creates the ZIP. (See Ivan Zuzak's comment in the question.)

For anyone who stumbles upon this question, you can find it here: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap-server

They are doing what I (and Ivan) suspected: getting the raw files from http://raw.github.com and creating the ZIP from that.